# Get Creation Date

Tags: web3.js, sol

so one more ask. Searched for this, and only found 1 way to get the creation date of a token.

The way I found involved looping through every transaction, and then finding the first transaction and getting the date from teh black there.

But at 1000 tx limit, this takes FOREVER.

Couldn't find any other way to get the date/timestamp a token was created.

Is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that's your only option. The validator only stores the state that it needs to process transactions and resolve forks, and mainly transactions are stored in a longterm way accessible via RPC.

There might be indexing services out there to help do this more easily, but with just the RPC endpoints, you'll need to iterate through the transactions to find the creation date.

Comment: Ooooofffff thats rough. Seems like none of the creation timestamps are stored anywhere either as part of the token metadata, etc. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example of how to query first activity of the given account from indexed db of dune.com

```
SELECT
  *
FROM solana.account_activity
WHERE
    address = {{ address }}
ORDER BY
  block_time
LIMIT 1
```